# Problema com strings acentuadas

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou recebendo uma *string* em um AJAX, porém, caso essa *string* tenha um acento ela não funciona como deveria.

```
$texto = $_REQUEST['texto_de'];
$texto_escrito = 'AB Construções e Serviços';

if($texto == $texto_escrito){
    echo "igual";
}
```

Estou rodando o seguinte AJAX no browser:

```
http://urlajax.com?texto_de=AB Construções e Serviços
```

Isso está me causando problemas, pois mais pra frente no código preciso rodar um `preg_replace`, porém ele não identifica que a *string* é igual.

Comment: Já fez um `var_dump($texto)` para ver o que chegou no PHP?

Comment: var_dump($texto); //retornou string(34) "AB Construções e Serviços"
 
var_dump($texto_escrito); //retornou string(31) "AB Construções e Serviços"

Comment: Percebi que o problema acontece apenas quando copio e colo o texto do html de origem do ajax.

Comment: Quando é a aplicação que roda o ajax ela acaba não funcionando, sabe algum jeito de padronizar tudo?